# Ajax phpmyadmin alternative?

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

I must say, I'm bored of phpmyadmin. We are in 2009 and I have to work with this useful tool and to wait every page to reload after every action. Are any ajaxed alternatives out there? Maybe phpmyadmin himself is going to be ajaxized?

Comment: Would you prefer a useless tool?

Comment: Well this sucks. It's 2012, phpmyadmin is still slow and cumbersome, and there are still no worthwhile alternatives. I don't have anything against hitting the shell, which in fact is usually way faster, but sometimes a decent GUI would help save time.

Comment: I also don't think the later updates of phpmyadmin have contributed to anything else than slower DB management. It would be nice with an up-to-date manager with a modern GUI.

Comment: After installing WinCache for my IIS server I noticed that phpMyAdmin got remarkable faster (as did all PHP scripts), even to the point that  I don't find myself waiting for it.

Answer (score 15):

These aren't necessarily AJAX but thought I'd list them as they may be useful to other people:

- [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/en/)
- [phpminiadmin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Adminer is the former phpMinAdmin.

Comment: Adminer is the fastest coolest admin ever!

Comment: @AlixAxel Although you're right, do note that phpMinAdmin != phpMiniAdmin.

Comment: Adminer in versions 3.2.0 - 3.3.4 is a fully AJAX application.

Answer (score 8):

[Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) (previously known as phpMinAdmin) is an excellent solution. I'm using only Adminer for a lot of my projects. In their homepage you can see a list of features and some screenshots. Here you can see a detailed [comparison of adminer vs phpmyadmin](http://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/)

- It support multiple database engines (currently, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS SQL, Oracle)
- Support translation (As of now, <strike>20</strike> 23 languages available)
- Skin-able by CSS
- [Support plugins](http://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/)
- [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/), Joomla extension, Drupal module, TYPO3 extension
- PHP 4.3.3+ and PHP 5
- Free even for commercial use
- [Online Adminer demo](http://adminer.sourceforge.net/adminer.php?username=)

They also have a specialized DB editing interface called [Adminer Editor](http://www.adminer.org/en/editor/).

Answer (score 7):

MonoQL! http://demo.monoql.com/

Answer (score 6):

Try [Dblite](http://dblite.com). It's powerful AJAX alternative to phpmyadmin and in some ways even better than the Desktop clients like SQLYog or Navicat. It has got a demo site [demo.dblite.com](http://demo.dblite.com) as well as full featured cloud-hosted online version [user.dblite.com](http://user.dblite.com).

Answer (score 5):

Try [SQLyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/). It offers much more than the PhpMyAdmin, but this is not a web-interface and its more like SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I added [MyWebSQL](http://mywebsql.net) as an answer to this question, and stackoverflow community deleted my answer. May I humbly ask what wrong did that answer do ?? Is this what stackoverflow is all about? biased asnwers and ratings?

Answer (score 3):

MonoQL is the answer.  A modern AJAX client tool for phpMyAdmin.  Check it out: http://demo.monoql.com.  You can download it from sourceforge...

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently trying [SIDU 3.2 DB Web GUI](http://sidu.sourceforge.net/sidu/)

Looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

I currently using [dbninja.com](http://www.dbninja.com) for my stuff. Amazing web based technology.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a forum, but you'll unlock commenting with a few upvotes. In the meantime please use the Answer button for actual answers only.

Answer (score 3):

There was a previous recommendation here for [MyWebSQL](http://mywebsql.net/) (not sure where the post went). It's very light and quick, found it quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).  Manage multiple servers, supports databases other than MySQL like PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, SQLite, Oracle, etc. and has a PHP bridge if your MySQL instance doesn't allow remote access.

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin does use AJAX in the current versions. (yes, I realize the question is 2y old - but still worth mentioning IMO)

Answer (score 1):

I found this one, though I haven't tried it yet: [SQL Buddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/).

<s>PhpMyAdmin is [working on an AJAXified version](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Devel:AJAX) too, though it looks like progress is slow.</s>
Edit: they've abandoned this, apparently. (at least, the wiki page is deleted)

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about providing yourself with an admin tool, not having web-access, and don't mind spending some money, I'd recommend [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql). I love having one program to manage MySQL across multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

i know this thread is old.... just for the reference I'm adding another one
http://mywebsql.net/

Answer (score 1):

Big improvements in phpMyAdmin 3.4.0

**Now** supports AJAX (partially) and editing data and queries inline.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [chive](http://www.chive-project.com/) since a while and pretty happy with it.

Powered by Yii Framework, it has all the features of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This is 10x better than PHPMyAdmin, and it looks modern too.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Buddy might look cute, be fast and better than Phpmyadmin, but it has its limitations. It doesn't let you convert data upon insert, I mean say you want to enter data directly into the database like a user and the password field stores a SHA1 hash of the password, Phpmyadmin lets you convert your input to SHA1, MD5 and more, SQL Buddy doesn't. Small oversight, but it's something I find useful in a web SQL client.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be web based? If you really want the responsiveness of a client app, you could use something like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) (Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Another good alternative is: http://www.webdbadmin.com

It's in pretty early stages but looks very promising.